# FxCop Custom Rule Documentation. Why is my URL not found?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, fxcop

I wrote custom FxCop rules for our project. I wrote a wiki page documenting it.

Now I just want that a developer can press F1 on a CA warning and gets the documentation shown. Unfortunately, it does not work and I can't find any documentation about it.

I just put the url into the rules file like this:

```
<Rule TypeName="MyRule" Category="MyCategory" CheckId="MY0001">
    <Name>...</Name>
    <Description>...</Description>
    <Owner>Stefan Steinegger</Owner>
    <Url>http://ourwikiserver/MY0001.ashx</Url>
    <Resolution>...</Resolution>
    <MessageLevel Certainty="100">Error</MessageLevel>
    <FixCategories>Breaking</FixCategories>
</Rule>
```

When I press F1 on my own rules, I get the MS "document explorer" (aka help) showing documentation about the error list window (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895338.aspx).

Did anyone ever use this successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the Help Library will try to find the Rule name in the help library and indeed does not use the url contained int he rules.xml.

The FxCop Gui does, but then again that one doesn't open Visual Studio Help.